# Error: Must have class type

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I need to create a list of contacts and I keep getting this error in my code: expression must have class type.

Here's the code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

class PhoneApp {
public:

string FirstName;
string LastName;
string PhoneNumber;
string EmailID;

PhoneApp() {
    FirstName = "";
    LastName = "";
    PhoneNumber = "";
    EmailID = "";
}

void addContact(){
    cout << "Enter your contact's first name: ";
    cin >> FirstName;

    cout << "Enter your contact's last name: ";
    cin >> LastName;

    cout << "Enter your contact's phone number: ";
    cin >> PhoneNumber;

    cout << "Enter your contact's email address: ";
    cin >> EmailID;
}

void displayContact(){
    cout << "Here's your contact details: " << endl;
    cout << "FirstName: " << FirstName << endl;
    cout << "LastName: " << LastName << endl;
    cout << "PhoneNumber: " << PhoneNumber << endl;
    cout << "EmailID: " << EmailID << endl;
}

};

int main(){


PhoneApp myPhoneApp[50];
int index = 0;

while(1){

    cout << "Press 1 to add contacts" << endl;
    cout << "Press 2 to search for a contact" << endl;
    cout << "Anything else to quit" << endl;
    int choice;
    cin >> choice;

    switch(choice){

    case 1:{ myPhoneApp[index].addContact();
        index++;
        break;}

    case 2: { cout << "Enter a first name to search for: " << endl;
        string search = "";
        cin >> search;
        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {       
            if(myPhoneApp[50].FirstName[i].compare(index) == 0);
            break;
            }
            }

    default: exit(1);
    }

}



system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

The error pops up at

```
if(myPhoneApp[50].FirstName[i].compare(index) == 0
```

What exactly is the problem here and how do I fix it?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Not an answer, but you don't need to assign your `std::string`s to empty string literals.

Comment: Which overload of `string.compare()` takes an `int` argument?  Also, `if(/*stuff*/);` isn't going to do what you want it to do.

Comment: Also `myPhoneApp[50]` out of boundry

Comment: Why are you doing `compare(index)`? What does that do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cout << "Enter a first name to search for: " << endl;
string search = "";
cin >> search;
for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {       
    if(myPhoneApp[i].FirstName.compare(search) == 0) {
        //do stuff
        break;
    }
}
```

Several things were going wrong.

First off, you need to compare the entire `FirstName` string to `search`, not individual characters of `FirstName`.

Second, you need to iterate through the contacts in `myPhoneApp[]`, not just keep checking different characters of the `FirstName` string in `index 50`, which isn't even necessarily set.

Third, no `string.compare()` overloads take a single `int` as an argument.  What you're looking for is the method to compare two strings, which is what my answer will do.

Fourth, an issue you didn't get to yet... you had a semicolon after your `if` statement, so regardless of the condition of the `if` statement, nothing really executes... and you'd just hit that `break;` after a single iteration, no matter what.

dashblinkenlight's answer explains why the error message was what it was, mine shows you how to fix your program.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple errors in your code, but the one that you are pointing to is as follows:

- `myPhoneApp[50].FirstName` is a `string`
- Strings consist of characters. You access characters in a string using a subscript operator `[i]`
- Characters are primitives.
- You can access members using a dot `.` on classes and structures, but not on primitives
- Since `myPhoneApp[50].FirstName[i]` is a `char`, and since `char` is a primitive, using a dot on it is invalid.

Comment: Your explanation went a bit over my head but I think I get the gist  it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are several small things coming together here to cause you a problem.

```
if(myPhoneApp[50].FirstName[i].compare(index) == 0);
    break;
```

Firstly: You have a stray semicolon on the end of the "if" line

```
if();
```

means "do the test, and then forget about it. always do the thing on the next line".

Secondly, you are only ever checking one element of your contacts list

```
myPhoneApp[50]
```

surely you mean't

```
myPhoneApp[i]
```

Next, `myPhoneApp[50].Firstname` resolves to a single instance of std::string, you then try to index the letters in that name and compare them with the number of entries in your index.

```
myPhoneApp[50].FirstName[i].compare(index)
```

What you presumably mean is

```
if(myPhoneApp[i].FirstName == search)
    break;
```

---- Edit ----

You've given your member variables of "myPhoneApp" upper-camelcase names, just like your class names. This is going to confuse you, and it means you can't name your member variables to match their type:

```
PhoneApp PhoneApp;
```

is a compile error.

A common practice is to give member variables distinctive names by adding a prefix ("m_" for member) or suffix (some places add "_" to indicate a member variable).

E.g.

```
class PhoneApp {
public:

    string m_FirstName;
    string m_LastName;
    string m_PhoneNumber;
    string m_EmailID;

    PhoneApp() {
        m_FirstName = "";
        m_LastName = "";
        m_PhoneNumber = "";
        m_EmailID = "";
    }
};
```

or "m_firstName", "m_lastName" etc.